# C++ Template explicit rvalue type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace mine {

    template <typename T>
    struct remove_rval {
        using type = T;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct remove_rval<T&&> {
        using type = T;    
    };

    template <typename T>
    void g(const T& = typename remove_rval<T>::type())
       cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;        
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    mine::g<int&&>(); // doesn't work, because of explicit template?
    const int& i2 = mine::remove_rval<int&&>::type(); // works, sanity check
    
    return 0;
}
```

The function template I wrote fails to compile. From my understanding of c++, you can assign an rvalue to a constant lvalue reference. But, in this situation, it is like the deduced type disregards the 'const' qualifier when assigning the function default value. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [dcl.ref/p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref):

> If a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or a *decltype-specifier* ([dcl.type.decltype]) denotes a type TR that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to create the type *lvalue reference to cv `TR`* **creates the type *lvalue reference to `T`***, while an attempt to create the type *rvalue reference to cv TR* creates the type `TR`.

Thus in your example, **when `T = int&&`** :
`const T&` collapses to `T&`(which is`int&`) and **not** `const T&`(which is `const int&`) according to the above quoted statement. And since we can't bind an *rvalue* like `remove_rval<T>::type()` to a *non-const lvalue reference*, you get the mentioned error.

Thus, even though the form of the function parameter in `g` is a *reference to const `T`* aka *const lvalue reference*(i.e., `const T&`), the first call to `g` **instantiates** `g` with a *reference to **non-const** `T`* aka *non-const lvalue reference*(i.e., `T&` =`int&`)  as the parameter:

```
template<>
void g<int &&>(int&)
{
  //operator<< called here
}
```

And since the parameter is `int&`, we cannot bind an *rvalue* like `remove_rval<int&&>::type()` to that parameter.

Comment: Appreciate the link. Really clarified the rule for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
void g(const T& = typename remove_rval<T>::type())
```

Reference collapsing rules make `const T&` equal to `U&` when `T = U&&`. Lvalue-references can't bind to temporaries like `remove_rval<T>::type()`. You can instead simply pass `int` as a template argument and the parameter's type will correctly be `const int&`.